# Citus support the HA? ( High Availability )

Tags: open-source, high-availability, citus

i have one simply question: citus 11 support the HA?
This is the structure that i have implemented with 7 node ( replication with pg_autofailover):

[image]

The problem occurs when i disable a worker1_primary and i try to make an sql insert in the coordinator_primary: the response of citus is: connection with remote worker1_primary refused.

The citus nodes table is this one ( from select * from pg_dist_node ):
[image]

thanks in advance for any reply

Comment: i am trying to achieve the same. have you installed citus first or pg_auto_failer over?

Comment: I tried with first setup citus with 3 node and then create monitor and then add existing citus node as primary and create secondary node.

Comment: I was getting error while adding primary node in monitor using pg_autoctl. It override my existing settings of pg_hba.cnf and data.

Comment: The installation order is not important: you can install citus first or pg_auto_failover. For use an existing postgres cluster you can use a PGDATA variable to pass it to pg_auto_failover. For example PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/14/main. if you use a PGDATA=./primary it create a new data cluster in the directory of postgres user.

Comment: Okay Got it. They are adding support for citus open source in pg_auto_failover.

Comment: You can find it over there. https://github.com/citusdata/pg_auto_failover/pull/933